# Extracting data from a Trie

Tags: java, recursion

I have implemented a generic trie which is able to store data, but my problem centers around extracting it from the trie. Here are my Trie and TrieNode classes, along with my getWords() method:

```
public class Trie<T extends Comparable<T>> 
{
    private TrieNode root;
    List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();

    public Trie()
    {
        root = new TrieNode((T) " ");
    }

    private class TrieNode implements Comparable 
    {
        private T data;
        private int count;
        private boolean end;
        private List<TrieNode> children; //subnodes

        private TrieNode(T data)
        {
            this.data = data;
            count = 0;
            end = false;
            children = new ArrayList<TrieNode>();
        }
        }

    public List<String> getWords(Trie<T> t) throws Exception
    {
        List<String> words = getWords(t.root);
        return words;
    }

    private List<String> getWords(TrieNode node) throws Exception
    {
        if(node.data.equals(" "))
        {
            if(node.children.size() > 0)
            {
                for(TrieNode x : node.children)
                    return getWords(x);

                return wordList;
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("Root has no children");
        }
        else if(node.children.size() > 0 && node.end == false)
        {
            word.append(node.data);

            for(TrieNode x : node.children)
                return getWords(x);
        }
        else if(node.children.size() == 0 && node.end == true)
        {
            word.append(node.data);
            wordList.add(word.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm testing with the following code in my main class:

```
    Trie<String> a = new Trie<String>();
    String[] word = "Steve".split("");
    a.insert(word);

    System.out.println(a.search(word)); //it can find the word in the trie
    System.out.println(a.getWords(a)); //but returns null when traversing through it
```

and the output is:

```
    true
    null
```

What is wrong with my code that it can't traverse correctly through the trie to extract the words stored within it?

Comment: It seems odd to me that you're mixing a generic data type `T` and strings.

Comment: Matt, once I get this working, I'll change the data type to T

Comment: @BheshGurung see the OP's reply to my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getWords(TrieNode)` implementation is returning early:

```
// ...
else if(node.children.size() > 0 && node.end == false)
{
    word.append(node.data);

    for(TrieNode x : node.children)
        return getWords(x); // here
}
// ...
```

That `return` line breaks the `for` loop on the very first iteration by returning `getWords(x)` for whatever the first `x` is. A possible fix (I'm not sure I fully understand what `getWords` is logically meant to return):

```
// ...
else if(node.children.size() > 0 && node.end == false)
{
    word.append(node.data);

    List<String> toReturn = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(TrieNode x : node.children) {
        toReturn.addAll(getWords(x));
    }

    return toReturn;
}
// ...
```

Comment: Honesty, I'm not exactly sure what `getWords()` is supposed to return in this case. Perhaps something like what's in my edit?

Comment: Matt, getWords() is supposed to traverse through the trie and return a List of all the words stored within it.

Comment: Okay, I sort of thought so. Let me know if you have any luck with my suggestion; it's a bit of a shot in the dark.

Comment: Alright, I'm going to settle down and get this done. Once it works, I'll let you know.